# Could not add entry '0' to cache localClassSetAnalysis.bin

Tags: android, android-studio

This project was running but today when i run it it gives this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    Could not add entry '0' to cache localClassSetAnalysis.bin (/home/blackgoogle/Desktop/SpeechToText/.gradle/2.10/tasks/_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac/localClassSetAnalysis/localClassSetAnalysis.bin).

this is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "timepass.vectorx.com.speechtotext"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.nuance:speechkit:2.1+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

and this one is project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please guys help....

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**In your Project SpeechToText .gradle is hidden folder,that's it is not visible**

Run this command in Ubuntu....

```
rm -f -r home/blackgoogle/Desktop/SpeechToText/.gradle/2.10/tasks/_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac/localClassSetAnalysis

rm -f -r home/blackgoogle/Desktop/SpeechToText/.gradle/2.10/tasks/_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac/localJarClasspathSnapshot
```

It may be work.......

Comment: for me i had to delete everything under `.gradle/2.10/tasks/` for it to work

Comment: I did `rm -rf my/android/project/.gradle` and then rebuild

Answer (score 12):

For Mac users run below command:

```
rm -rf /path/to/your/android/project/.gradle
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem today, goto

home/blackgoogle/Desktop/SpeechToText/.gradle/2.10/tasks/_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac/

as shown in your stack trace . You will have a few folders there(localClassSetAnalysis & localJarClasspathSnapshot). Delete all of them and try again .Basically they add .lock because of which gradle is not able to act on those dirs.

This worked for me

Comment: there is not any .gradle folder inside the SpeechToText folder.

Comment: This solved it for me!  My PC crashed in the middle of a build.

Comment: @sushildlh maybe in C:\Users\_\.gradle.

Comment: @sushildlh Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944998/where-is-the-gradle-directory-in-ubuntu/37945063#37945063

Comment: Deleting the folders inside ..\_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac as suggested by Kartik did the trick  for me.  Thanks Kartik

Answer (score 6):

If you using android studio,

1.) Open your project.

2.) Go to your project structure, and remove .gradle directory and sync project.

3.) Run application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this folder:-

**/home/blackgoogle/Desktop/SpeechToText/.gradle/2.10/tasks/_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac/localClassSetAnalysis**
delete all the contents of this folder.
This folder might be hidden so view hidden files.

Now, rebuild the project.
This is because they add .lock files in the folder automatically because of which gradle is not able to act on those dirs. Once you remove them it will work normally.