# Where is the .gradle directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

In Windows, it is: `C:\Users\me\.gradle`. But what about Ubuntu? Is it in a different location? If so, where?

I've searched everywhere but can't to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be located under `$HOME/.gradle` (`~/.gradle`) and/or (project specific) `<PROJECT_DIR>/.gradle`.

Comment: Might also add ~/.gradle to that list.

Comment: @Jolta, added however as far as I know it's equivalent to `$HOME`.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a user hasn't messed up their environment to the point where $USER is undefined. =)

Comment: @Jolta There is also no guarantee that the user hasn't set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to point somewhere random. We're talking about defaults aren't we?

Answer (score 1):

`/home/<your-user-name>/.gradle`

is equivalent to,

`~/.gradle`