# Android Studio 4 build failed cause error=2 no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I am new to Android Studio I just opened a template as normal as anybody can do when first open android studio, I didn't edit anything I just tried to build the apk and got that error, can someone help?

````
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #12: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #11: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-linux Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.```
````

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-projec

Comment: Not duplicating there is some difference between my error and his error

Answer (score 0):

Try following options:

1. clean & rebuild your project
2. Restart the android studio
3. Try Invalidate caches and restart
4. Delete `C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches` folder and restart Android
   studio
5. Check and Update your android gradle plugin version

Also check your `gradle.properties` contain below line or not.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: For the 4th one I am using Ubuntu not windows

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945063/2078074) to find `.gradle` folder in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Spent weeks on and off with an **AAPT2** error: `no such file or directory`
despite the file concerned being present and not malformed/corrupt (the underlying problem in all the solutions I found online)

I finally discovered that **AAPT2** uses the `mmap()` C library call to map resources into memory for the merge process (AAPT did not.)

My projects were on a network share (SSHFS), which caused an **mmap error** the **AAPT2** code was not expecting, resulting in the inaccurate error message.

### The only solutions I could find were:

1. Don't use a network share (who needs networks right?)
2. Rewrite AAPT2 to not use mmap.